# I want to replace a word in a string, with different words from a dictionary created from pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

please help me out with this ..
I want to replace a word in a string, with different words from a dictionary created from pandas

For example

```
txt = "<I love *NAME*, it is *COLOR* in color, Its price is *PRICE*>"

dict = [{'NAME':'APPLE','COLOR' : 'RED', 'PRICE' : '100'},{'NAME':'MANGO','COLOR' : 'YELLOW', 'PRICE' : '300'}

output = "<I love APPLE, it is RED in color, Its price is 100><I love MANGO, it is YELLOW in color, Its price is 300>
```

CODE USED :

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

txt = "<I love *NAME*, it is *COLOR* in color, Its price is *PRICE*>"

filename= r'Input.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(filename)

d = df.to_dict(orient='records')

for row in d:

 txt=txt.replace("*NAME*",row['NAME']).replace("*COLOR*",row['COLOR']).replace("*PRICE*",str(row['PRICE']))

print(txt)
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: If you can change the `txt` string to have `{...}` instead of `*...*`, you could utilize the `format` method and do `print(txt.format(**row))`

Comment: And I can only guess that your problem is that you only see the last row printed right? Try to print **_inside_** the loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used regex in your example .

```py
import re

txt = "<I love *NAME*, it is *COLOR* in color, Its price is *PRICE*>"

dicts = [{'NAME':'APPLE','COLOR' : 'RED', 'PRICE' : '100'},{'NAME':'MANGO','COLOR' : 'YELLOW', 'PRICE' : '300'}]

# output = "<I love APPLE, it is RED in color, Its price is 100><I love MANGO, it is YELLOW in color, Its price is 300>

pattern = r"\*[A-Z]+\*?"
matches = re.findall(pattern, txt)

output_list = []
for i in range(len(dicts)):
    tempTxt = txt
    for word in matches:
        tempTxt = tempTxt.replace(word, dicts[i][word[1:-1]])
    output_list.append(tempTxt)
output = "".join(output_list)
```

---

You can also use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) instead of combining `re.findall` and `str.replace`. This will find your pattern, and replace the match with the replacement from the dict. Notice the use of a capture group (`(...)`) to make things easier:

```py
import re

txt = "<I love *NAME TYPE*, it is *COLOR* in color, Its price is *PRICE*>"

dicts = [{'NAME TYPE':'APPLE','COLOR' : 'RED', 'PRICE' : '100'},{'NAME TYPE':'MANGO','COLOR' : 'YELLOW', 'PRICE' : '300'}]

pattern = r"\*([^*]+)\*"

for d in dicts:
    print(re.sub(pattern, lambda match: d[match[1]], txt))
```

Notice that instead of using an explicit replacment string, we use a function taking a `Match` object. This function simply returns the value from the dict where the string between the `*` is the key.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rhLmdp/1)

Comment: hey, what if instead of *NAME* it is *NAME TYPE* . ( so what if there is a space in between the argument. what change in pattern will require ? please let me know

Comment: @DarshilLakhani you can change the pattern to `\*[^*]+\*`

Comment: or You may change the patten to something like this also . ```pattern = r"\*[\S\s]+?\*" ```. More general is @Tomerikoo s method.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `[\S\s]` is basically the same as `.`... By the way, you can change the whole loop to one line, by using `re.sub` instead of `str.replace`: `output_list.append(re.sub(pattern, lambda match: dict[i][match[1]], txt))`

Comment: Please do the editing. I can also learn. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Well I guess if you approve... :)

Comment: How can I approve .? Please tell me .

Comment: No haha I meant that I don't usually add to other's answers, but if you don't mind I will. Check my edit. Hope you can learn from it :)))

Comment: hello, thanks a lot everyone for help, this code worked for me ..import re

txt = "<I love *NAME TYPE*, it is *COLOR* in color, Its price is *PRICE*>"

dicts = [{'NAME TYPE':'APPLE','COLOR' : 'RED', 'PRICE' : '100'},{'NAME TYPE':'MANGO','COLOR' : 'YELLOW', 'PRICE' : '300'}]

pattern = r"\*([^*]+)\*"

for d in dicts:
    print(re.sub(pattern, lambda match: d[match[1]], txt))

Comment: @Tomerikoo please suggest me if i want to add conditions to it as, IF a particular key has A B or C value for example. then i want to use different strings for replacing .. logic being there are 3 to 4 templates which are to be used in connection to a particular key value pair in the dictionary. how is that possible ?

Comment: Can you please post that as a separate question. ? With what you want to achieve ?